# Array reduce is not returning expected results

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a search function that is getting passed through an array filter, followed by a reduce to match the correct strings to each other but I'm experiencing some difficulties getting the expected results.

I have an enum of common phrases that I want to map to their values, for instance if `Amer` is searched it should also match `American`. To achieve this I've setup an object with some values with a reduce that should add the value to the search string, for instance if either the API data or the search data contains `U Street African Amer` it should turn it into `u street african amer american` in the return. If it doesn't find any mapped data it should pass back the original function arguement.

```js
const acronymEnum = {
  MT: 'Mountain',
  AMER: 'American',
  PL: 'Place',
  UDC: 'Univeristy of the District of Columbia',
  AU: 'American University',
  AVE: 'Avenue',
  CUA: 'Catholic University of America',
  NOMA: 'North of Massechusets Avenue',
  GMU: 'George Mason University',
  VT: 'Virginia Tech',
  UVA: 'University of Virginia',
  RAEGAN: 'DCA',
  ST: 'Street',
  SW: 'South West',
  SQ: 'Square',
  PENN: 'Pennsylvania',
};

function convertStationAcronym(stationName) {
  return Object.keys(acronymEnum).reduce((previous, current) => {
    if (stationName.toLowerCase().includes(current.toLowerCase())) {
      console.log('trigger the match', current)
      return stationName.concat(` ${acronymEnum[current]}`).toLowerCase();
    } else {
     return previous.toLowerCase();
    }
  }, '');
}

console.log(convertStationAcronym('U Street African Amer'))
```

The issue I'm running into is that it's returning either undefined, or it's adding only one mapped phrase to the return depending on what is passed into the function. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try use the stationName instead of empty string in reduce method

Comment: Whatever solution you write for this problem using reduce will, in my opinion, be more difficult to understand, more fragile, and less performant than the very obvious and very simple for loop solution.

Comment: Please give us more test cases. Like `U Street/African-Amer Civil War Memorial/Cardozo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to start the `reduce` with `stationName` as the initial value, and then always concatenate to `previous` not the original `stationName` value:

```js
const acronymEnum = {
  MT: 'Mountain',
  AMER: 'American',
  PL: 'Place',
  UDC: 'Univeristy of the District of Columbia',
  AU: 'American University',
  AVE: 'Avenue',
  CUA: 'Catholic University of America',
  NOMA: 'North of Massechusets Avenue',
  GMU: 'George Mason University',
  VT: 'Virginia Tech',
  UVA: 'University of Virginia',
  RAEGAN: 'DCA',
  ST: 'Street',
  SW: 'South West',
  SQ: 'Square',
  PENN: 'Pennsylvania',
};

function convertStationAcronym(stationName) {
  return Object.keys(acronymEnum).reduce((previous, currentKey) => {
    const re = new RegExp("\\b" + currentKey + "\\b", "i"); // TODO: escape special characters
    if (re.test(stationName)) {
      console.log('trigger the match', currentKey)
      return previous.concat(' ', acronymEnum[currentKey]);
//           ^^^^^^^^
    } else {
     return previous;
    }
  }, stationName).toLowerCase();
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^
}

console.log(convertStationAcronym('U Street African Amer'))
```

Comment: @greentec `st` is part of `u street …`. Yes, it might not exactly be what the OP expected, but I wanted to fix only the issue that they asked about and not come up with a completely new approach that might have been more appropriate to solve the problem (or introduce exact matches instead of using `includes`?).

Comment: I edited your answer with exact regexp word match. Can you update answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative solution to the problem can be dividing the input string into an array and for each element in the array, we will find the entry in acronymEnum Object. This approach will be more efficient if the length of the input string is less.

```js
const acronymEnum = {
  MT: 'Mountain',
  AMER: 'American',
  PL: 'Place',
  UDC: 'Univeristy of the District of Columbia',
  AU: 'American University',
  AVE: 'Avenue',
  CUA: 'Catholic University of America',
  NOMA: 'North of Massechusets Avenue',
  GMU: 'George Mason University',
  VT: 'Virginia Tech',
  UVA: 'University of Virginia',
  RAEGAN: 'DCA',
  ST: 'Street',
  SW: 'South West',
  SQ: 'Square',
  PENN: 'Pennsylvania',
};

function convertStationAcronym(stationName) {
  let stationNameArray = stationName.split(" ");
  let result =  stationNameArray.map((item)=> { 
    return acronymEnum[item.toUpperCase()] 
      ? acronymEnum[item.toUpperCase()]
      :item 
  })
  return result.join(" ");
}

console.log(convertStationAcronym('U Street African Amer'))
```

Comment: The main problem with this solution is that sometimes the data is not always separated by spaces. It can be `U Street/African-Amer Civil War Memorial/Cardozo` for instance and therefore it won't change Amer to American. When it appends the string it's not as much of an issue because it will still trigger the search case.